# Quais cuidados devo tomar para criar uma página de checkout?

Tags: javascript, react, segurança, pagamento-online

Olá!

Estou desenvolvendo um e-commerce em ReactJs e fazendo a integração com o PagSeguro e, apesar de ser possível usar a página de checkout deles, gostaria de criar a minha e só enviar os dados (Dados do cartão, vencimento, etc) para o processamento deles.

Gostaria de saber se existem cuidados especiais para lidar com a captação desses dados sensíveis ou posso guardar as informações dos `inputs` diretamente em estados como qualquer outro dado e enviar para a minha API que fará a conexão com a API do PagSeguro.

Obrigado.

Comment: Depende do tipo de integração. Se você está coletando os dados do cartão, então você precisa seguir o PCI DSS. Isso é mencionado na página do próprio PagSeguro ("Nosso serviço de cobrança permite o envio dos dados de cartão de crédito abertos única e exclusivamente para vendedores PCI Compliance."), em https://dev.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v4.0/docs/cobrando-com-cartao-de-credito.

Comment: Ainda estou me adaptando à documentação do pagseguro, e sua resposta me ajudou bastante, muito obrigado. Como ainda não tenho o PCI DSS vou seguir com o checkout transparente que eles sugerem. Muito obrigado!